# Creating class with collection in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class that represents a person

**Person.cls**

```
Option Explicit
'the person class
Public FirstName As String
Public LastName As String
```

and another class to hold a list of people

**PersonList.cls**

```
Dim person_list As Collection
```

I have a module

**testPersons.bas**

```
Public Sub testPersons()
    Dim p1 As New clsPerson
    p1.FirstName = "Rita"
    p1.LastName = "Smith"

    Dim persons2 As New PersonList
    persons2.person_list.Add p1
End Sub
```

When I run the module I get a compile error: "Method or data member not found."

I tried creating a subroutine `addPerson` to PersonList, but I can't figure out how to make that work.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, here is what I have now:

**Person.cls**

```
Option Explicit
Public FirstName As String
Public LastName As String
```

**PersonList.cls**

```
Public person_list As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set person_list = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub addPerson(this_person As Person)
    person_list.Add this_person
End Sub
```

**testPersons.bas**

```
Public Sub testPersons()
    Dim p1 As New Person
    p1.FirstName = "Rita"
    p1.LastName = "Smith"

    Dim persons_list As New PersonList
    persons_list.addPerson p1
End Sub
```

And...**it works!**

However, `persons_list.addPerson(p1)` gives "`Run-time error: 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.`" I guess I don't understand VBA syntax for calling methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recreated your project with the names you gave us.
The line that gets the compiler error is right here.

> Dim p1 As New clsPerson

This is because your class is named `Person` and not `clsPerson`. 
Dropping the prefix should fix the compiler error.

***But***...

You're going to run into your next problem very soon.

> Dim person_list As Collection

This declares the person list privately. You'll need to expose it by making it public to work with it. But there's a little more to it than that. You'll also need to add a `Class_Initialize` routine to your class so that you actually have a collection object to work with.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set person_list = New Collection
End Sub
```

---

I just noticed that you wanted to keep that collection private, so in addition to the class initializer, you'll need to add this method too.

```
Public Sub Add(value As Person)
    person_list.Add value
End Sub
```

Comment: Works. Just a question -- I called my method addPerson, rather than overloading the add function. But I get a difference between calling the function with parenthesis or not (see my edits above). Care to comment and educate me ;)

Comment: Well, no... Not because I'm mean, but because that's rightfully a completely different question. You should create a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: @abalter the parentheses are forcing an evaluation.  Your `PersonList` class does not have a suitable `Get` method for the `person_list` property.